# Displacement Modifier Not Behaving As Before

Tags: displacement, origin

I have been playing with displacement modifiers for 3D printing, having good results, however once I started using UV Editing to get better alignments for textures the original style of using Local Coordinates has stopped giving the results it used to.

I used to use *Affect Only Origins*, which yields good results, but causes problems later down the line with he origin, being out of wack.

[image: Transformed Origin to manipulate texture behaviour]

I have cross referenced as many settings and variables as I can on older models but cannot find anything that is different. I have copied and pasted, meshes with displacement modifier behaving as expected and put it next to misbehaving meshed and get two entirely different results.
I have even factory reset Blender but still get the same results.

[image: side by side.]

[Project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iomNyBvYfz451bOqrpsiIcAPH_Wn2bq/view?usp=sharing)